# MvvmCross: How to use multiple test classes derived from MvxIoCSupportingTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvmcross

I have two xUnit test classes, derived from MvxIoCSupportingTest.
Running my unit tests I receive the error message:

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException : You should only initialize MvxBindingSingletonCache once
```

Is there a way to explicitly instatiate the IoC not as signleton?

Answer (score 2):

Use this class instead of MvxIoCSupportingTest

```
using MvvmCross.Core;
using MvvmCross.Core.Platform;
using MvvmCross.Platform.IoC;
using MvvmCross.Platform.Platform;

namespace MvvmCross.Test.Core
{
    public class BaseMvvmCrossTest
    {
        static BaseMvvmCrossTest()
        {
            if (MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Instance == null)
            {
                MvxSingletonCache.Initialize();
                MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialize();

                MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Instance.RegisterSingleton(MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Instance);
                MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Instance.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTrace>(new TestTrace());
                MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Instance.RegisterSingleton<IMvxSettings>(new MvxSettings());

                MvxTrace.Initialize();
            }
        }
    }
}
```